# Parameters of operations in Visio's Class diagram

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2007

I am drawing a Class diagram in Visio.
In the operations part of a class, I would like to show the parameters.

For example: doMethod(String hi): void.

But I don't know how to set the parameters.

Can anyone please suggest a way?

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean by "set parameters". Are you trying to add more Parameters like "hi" to doMethod, or trying to figure out how to provide a value for "hi" when running doMethod?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you're using a UML diagram

Double click on the method you've created (called operation), select the operation in question then select properties from right side menu, from here you can add the paramaters.

[image]