# Visio to show my functions (Process) relationships

Tags: microsoft-visio-2010, diagrams, uml

I want to draw a chart to show programming functions relationship together.
Imagine I've 3 functions:

```
Function a1(a,b)
{
//Do something
}

Function a2(x)
{
//Do something
}

Function a3()
{
    Function a1(10,20)
    Function a2(50)
}
```

I want to show in a diagram that I have 3 functions with some inputs and how functions call each others. I've tried MS Visio but I don't know how to show functions input parameters. I've also used Visual paradigm software to draw class diagrams, there I could specify functions' input and their types but couldn't put them in a workflow.

How can I do this with Visio?

Comment: You need to search for UML diagrams I think... Any way, software recommendations are off topic here.

Comment: Where can I ask for a software recommendation?

Comment: I'm going to edit your question, to make it on topic, then hopefully you will get an answer for it

Comment: Actually, this may be a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/529843/parameters-of-operations-in-visios-class-diagram/529848#529848

Answer (score 0):

In Visio there is the option to create a UML diagram, under software and databases.

Within the UML diagram, you can specify the parameters (including the types).

Because there are so many options here, I can't copy all the data into this post, apologies for a link but http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/visio-help/work-with-classes-and-objects-in-uml-static-structure-diagrams-HP001209086.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Would you please only tell me where is the shape and how to specify parameters? I couldn't find that in your link :(